# How to setup http client before injection?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a class `ApiClient` which executes http requests to the external service. I guess that it's idiomatic to inject `HttpClient` to simplify testing instead of setting it inside. What are the ways to do that? Where should I setup this client and how to force Spring to inject it to `ApiClient`?

Comment: Make it a bean, inject it?

Comment: @123 I don't know how to make it a bean. Should I create a wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a bean

```
@Configuration
public class ApiClientConfig {

    @Bean
    HttpClient httpClient(){
        //Create httpClient or build or get it however you want and return
        return HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    }


}
```

And then inject into your class

```
@Component
public class ApiClient {

    private final HttpClient httpClient;

    ApiClient(HttpClient httpClient){
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this but what I think you're talking about is quite simple. As @123 mentioned it is a matter of creating and injecting beans. Meta example using annotations:

```
package my.scanned.package
// ...
@Component
class ApiClient {
  @Autowired 
  HttpClient httpClient;
  // contructor methods etc
}
```

Then your Http client is similar:

```
package my.scanned.package
// ...
@Component
class HttpClient {
  // contructor methods etc
}
```

Then use those in something like `@Service`:

```
package my.scanned.package
// ...
@Service
class FooService {
  @Autowired
  ApiClient apiClient;

  Response callApi() {
    return apiClient.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Then again in tests it is gonna be easy to just mock those beans.